# Average datediff of 2 date in the same column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the average `datediff` of 2 dates that are in the same column for each consumer. The table looks like this:

| name | date | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mark | 2021-01-03 | send |
| mark | 2021-01-05 | arrived |
| ken | 2021-01-07 | send |
| ken | 2021-01-10 | arrived |
| mark | 2021-01-12 | send |
| mark | 2021-01-15 | arrived |

I need to get the average date diff of arrived and send for each customer.

Output should be like this:

| name | avg_date |
| --- | --- |
| mark | 2.5 |
| ken | 3 |

This is my code, but the output didn't match

```
SELECT
  name,
  AVG(DATEDIFF(day, (SELECT date FROM sell WHERE status='arrived'), (SELECT date FROM sell WHERE status='send')))
FROM sell
GROUP BY name
```

Can you help me fix the code? Thank you :)

Comment: So what's stopping you? What is your question?

Comment: When posting your question you were informed the following: *"Not all questions benefit from including code, but if your problem is better understood with code you’ve written, you should include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)."* Knowing your attempt(s) will most certainly help us help you here, as we can then explain where you went wrong. If you haven't written any code, then at least tell us what about the documentation/articles/tutorials you read you didn't understand (and cite them), so we can try to further explain.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for reminding me. sorry, this is my first time using stack overflow and just learning SQL. I fixed my question :)

Answer (score 0):

**This is a a classic gaps-and-islands problem.**

It is made easier by the fact that each island only has two rows, so you can just use `LAG` to get the other row.

> `DATEDIFF` only returns how many date boundaries are crossed. For accurate results, use `second` not `day`, and divide by the decimal `86400.0`

```sql
SELECT
  name,
  AVG(DATEDIFF(second, s.PrevDate, s.date) / 86400.0)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      PrevDate = LAG(s.date) OVER (PARTITION BY s.name ORDER BY s.date)
    FROM sell s
) s
WHERE s.status = 'arrived'
GROUP BY
  s.name;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1dd5489f03a6b3b732776206c8949f9f)